# Does having double cards increase the chance of using them in a mission?

Tags: pocket-mine

In Pocket Mine you can fuse duplicate cards. But if I don't fuse them but rather play on, do I have more (probably roughly doubled) chance to use that specific card in a mission?

Comment: you need to know about the source code or play a lot of games and create statistics in order to get a valid answer.

Comment: I was afraid so. Too bad, because it was a pretty good card and I would like to obtain it more times.